Sequence limit of an integral
Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on [-1,1] (but not necessarily continuous), $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=A\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the sequence limit: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x=\pi A$$.
I make the substitution $nx=u$ which transform the integral to $$\int_{-n}^{n} 
\frac{f(u/n)}{1+u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u$$ Intuitively, $f(u/n)$ approaches $A$ as $n$ increase, and the integral becomes an integral of $\frac{1}{1+u^2}$ over $(-\infty, \infty)$, which is $\pi$. I am hoping for a more rigorous proof.

How about applying the theorem of dominated convergence?

someone has already answered this before so here it goes: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/330067/1413301
